# C# Trim charaters from the end of string

Tags: c#

I have this string

> "1.3.1.\tProduction and Sales Analysis:"

I want to trim numbers and escape sequences from the start and end of string.

**Output Should be :**

> "Production and Sales Analysis:"

**My code :**

```
Char[] trimArray = new Char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.',',',':','\\','/'};
        String test = "1.3.1.\tProduction and Sales Analysis:";
        test = test.TrimEnd(trimArray);
```

> but problem is when a string like **23232-232123-asd-323** comes it also removes the digits
>
> I want to remove the unwanted characters from start and end of string **But** Want to keep the string like **23232-232123-asd-323 or mobile numbers**

Thanks.

Comment: I hate to say it, but use a `Regular Expression` :)

Comment: how can i use the regex? i have no idea about it

Comment: I don't know how a `TrimEnd` can remove the characters at the beginning of the string.

Comment: How you will distinguish bad "numbers" from 23232 "numbers"?

Comment: For example you could search for the `\t` character and, if present, take the string to the right of the `\t`

Comment: What does a mobile number look like in your locale, and what's so special about the string "23232-232123-asd-323"? Why don't you check those conditions first?

Comment: the string that contains more digits in it actually that string i want to keep.

Comment: mobile number are like 03XZ-YYYYYYY in my locale

Comment: you might try to keep your `unwanted chars`  in a `list`  and check from the `chararray` .

Answer (score 0):

Is there always '\t' in the middle?
You can try to split by '\t' and trim end.

```
Split(new char[]{'\t'});
```

If colon is always at the end of what you want to get you can split again ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is something in common separating the bad number and the good numbers like say "t", then how about finding the index of the common letter/symbol then creating a substring of everything after.  For example:

```
String test = "1.3.1.\tProduction and Sales Analysis:";

index = test.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { 't' });
test = test.Substring(index +1);
```

This should give you "Production and Sales Analysis:".  You could do the same for the ":" except you want everything before it like so

```
int index = test.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { ':' });
test = test.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "1.3.1.\tProduction and Sales Analysis:";
string rgx =  @"(?:[0-9.]+)*(?:\\[a-zA-Z])*([\w\s\.\:-_]+)(?:\\[a-zA-Z])*";
string result = Regex.Match(input, rgx).Groups[1].Value.TrimStart();
```